# How to use ImageMagick to test if received input is an image (for security purposes)?

Tags: security, imagemagick

Imagine an environment in which users can upload images to a website by either uploading it from their pc or referring to a remote url.

As part of some security checks I'd like to make sure that the referenced object is indeed an image.

In the case of a remote-url, I of course check the content-type, but this isn't bullet-proof.

I figured I could use ImageMagick to do the task. Perhaps executing the ImageMagick.identify() method and if no error is returned and returned type is either JPG|GIF|,etc. the content is an image. (In a quick check I noticed that TXT files are identified correctly as well, so I have to blacklist these)

Is there any better way in doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could probably simply load the image via ImageMagick's appropriate function for your language of choice. If the image isn't formatted properly (in terms of internal formatting, not its aesthetic properties, that is), I would expect ImageMagick to refuse to load it and report an error. In PHP, for example, readImage returns false if the image fails to load.

Alternatively, you could read the first few hundred bytes of the file and determine if the expected image file format headers are present; e.g., "GIF89" etc.

Answer (score 1):

These checks may backfire, if your image is in a compressable format (PNG, GIF) and it is constructed in a way similar to a zip bomb https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zip_bomb

Some examples at ftp://ftp.aerasec.de/pub/advisories/decompressionbombs/pictures/ (nothing special about that site, I just googled decompression bombs)

Another related issue is that formats like SVG are in fact XML and some image processing tools are prone to a variant of "billion laughs" attack https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Billion_laughs

Comment: Didn't know that thanks. Any thoughts on how to handle this for user uploaded pictures? I really can't find anything on how to protect against this.

Comment: I am not sure myself, perhaps forking out image processing code in a separate, Unix process and set it with quotas. Just a wild guess. I do not think a generic solution is possible.

Answer (score 0):

You should not store the original file. The generally recommended approach is to *always* re-process the image and convert it to an entirely new file. There have been vulnerabilites exploited inside valid image files (see [GIFAR](https://cve.mitre.org/cgi-bin/cvename.cgi?name=CVE-2008-5343)), so checking for this would have been useless.

Never expose your visitors to an image file that you have not written out yourself and for which you did not choose the file name yourself.

Comment: Actually I intended to reprocess the image/picture by Imagemagick like you suggest (resize 100% or whatever), but I figured I may need an extra check before even attempting that. On the other hand, failing this re-process might be enough indication of the input not being an image I guess.